# How to break long strings of text in a container with no width and overflow auto

Tags: html, css

I have a notifications window that populates list items (it can have no list items or lots of them).

I have an issue with long strings of text but due to there being no width on its container I'm not sure on the best approach to break them.

I tried using `word-wrap: break-word;` and `max-width` but the issue i found with that approach is that when there are few list items the scrollbar disappears (as expected) leaving a space.

Any ideas would be great... thanks in advance

[image: Needs to cut off here]

**HTML**

```
<ul class="container">

  <li id="" class="notification-item">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="notification">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" id="imgProfileasset" alt="user image" class="user-image-small border" height="30" width="30">
        <h2 class="sr-only">New Thread Post</h2>
        <p>lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text</p>
        <i class="icon-file"></i>
        <time class="timeago" datetime="2015-10-19T07:30:16.710+00:00" title="19/10/2015 08:30">41 minutes ago</time>
      </div>
    </a>
    <ul class="unstyled admin">
      <li><a style="cursor: default;" href="#" class="notification-read-btn" data-placement="top" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="notification read"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Icon</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="notification-options-btn" data-placement="top" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Options"><i class="icon-cog"></i> Icon</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.container {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 380px;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: white;
}

.notification {
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 55px;
}

.notification-item {
  position: relative;
}

.notification-item img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  word-wrap:break-word;

}

.admin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/haguem/9xv6nk4o/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to the css:

```
 .notification p {
     word-break: break-all;
 }
```

See it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/9xv6nk4o/3/

Comment: Sorry i should have mentioned that i need whole words .. when you use that it breaks all words im only looking to break large strings of text

Comment: That "large string of text" is only one word. If you don't want to break words, you will need to make something with javascript to add an space in the large string. No CSS method for your petition, sorry :( The only approach is that I serve you in my answer (break all)

Comment: I was thinking that myself but was hoping there might be a trick with table-layout or flex layouts and word-wrap ..

Comment: You haven't got tables, so `table-layout` is not a solution. However, `table-layout` won't fix your problem.